# I need help using sql statements about where conditions in my Django program

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

This is my program. I need to change the where condition in the SQL statement to be dynamically generated using a python program because sometimes a condition in my where the statement may have no value. I do n’t want him to appear in the SQL statement when there is no value. in

Thank you very much, I really need help, I'm a newbie, I can't figure it out

```
@csrf_exempt
def test(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        req_type = request.GET.get("get_data")
        if req_type:
            customer = request.GET.get('customer')
            order_type = request.GET.get("orderType")
            order_status = request.GET.get("orderStatus")
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(
                    "SELECT account,order_id,start_at,update_at "
                    "FROM once  WHERE user_id=%s OR %s='' AND order_id=%s OR %s='' AND status=%s OR  %s='' ORDER BY order_id DESC ",
                    (customer, customer, order_type, order_type, order_status,order_status))
                verify_list = dict_fetchall(cursor)
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(verify_list, cls=DecimalEncoder))
        else:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute('SELECT id,`name` FROM goods;')
                goods_data = cursor.fetchall()
            with connection.cursor() as cursor1:
                cursor1.execute('SELECT id,account FROM `user`;')
                user_data = cursor1.fetchall()
            content = {"goods_data": goods_data, "user_data": user_data}
            return render(request, 'user/test.html', content)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:login'))
```

Comment: in your code case write a function, which take `customer, customer, order_type, order_type, order_status,order_status` as input and check that if the input in None or not , if there is value then return the `user_id=%s OR %s='' AND order_id=%s OR %s='' AND status=%s ` add this output the the query execution

Comment: I don't want to make judgments in sql where, because the amount of data now does not allow me to do so

Answer (score 0):

if I have understood the question well, you may construct an sql query string dynamically, for example:

```
where = []

if customer:
    where.append(f"user_id={customer}")  # assuming customer is integer, put value without quotes
if order_type:
    where.append(f"order_id={order_type}")  # assuming order_type is integer, put value without quotes
if order_status:
    where.append(f"status='{order_status}'")  # assuming order_status is string, put value inside quotes

where = ' AND '.join(where)        
where = ('WHERE ' if where else '') + where

query = f"SELECT account, order_id, start_at, update_at FROM once {where} ORDER BY order_id DESC"

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your understanding of the topic. Your answer solved my problem. Thanks again.